# How to get randomly drawn rectangles to be vertically stacked next to each other?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I am trying to get randomly drawn rectangles to line up next to each other on a form but my loop is not working and giving me undesired results, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have already created a method that creates random rectangles and then stores them in the list collection.

```
    List<Rectangle> rectangleCollection = new List<Rectangle>();

    void CreateRectangle()
    {
        int TallestRectangle = 0; ;
        int PrevRecX = 0;
        int PrevRecY = 0;

        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
        Graphics graphic = this.CreateGraphics();


        foreach (Rectangle rect in rectangleCollection)
        {
            if (rect.Height > TallestRectangle) 
                TallestRectangle = rect.Height;
        }

        foreach (Rectangle rect in rectangleCollection)
        {
            if (PrevRecX + PrevRecY == 0)
            {
                graphic.DrawRectangle(pen, new Rectangle(rect.X, (TallestRectangle - rect.Height), rect.Width, rect.Height));
            }
            else
            {
                graphic.DrawRectangle(pen, new Rectangle((PrevRecX + PrevRecY), (TallestRectangle - rect.Height), rect.Width, rect.Height));
            }
            PrevRecX = rect.X;
            PrevRecY = rect.Width;
        }

    }

    void GetRandomRectangle()
    {
        Random ran = new Random();

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        int width = ran.Next(100, 500);
        int height = ran.Next(200, 700);

        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

        rectangleCollection.Add(rec);
    }
```

Comment: What "undesired result"? What do you get? How does that differ from what you expect?

Comment: If the problem is that all your rectangles are the same size: don't create a `Random` object every time you call `GetRandomRectangle`. Have *one* static one and use that.

Comment: @Corak My undesired result is that my rectangles are not aligning next to each other and are overlapping, also can you please give me an example of having a static Random object and using it(sorry I am a still new).

Answer (score 0):

Your second `foreach` looks way too complicated. And I don't think you really need `PrevRecX`. Try this and see if it does what you expect.

```
void CreateRectangle()
{
  int TallestRectangle = 0;
  int PrevRecY = 0;

  Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
  Graphics graphic = this.CreateGraphics();

  foreach (Rectangle rect in rectangleCollection)
  {
    if (rect.Height > TallestRectangle)
      TallestRectangle = rect.Height;
  }

  foreach (Rectangle rect in rectangleCollection)
  {
    graphic.DrawRectangle(pen, new Rectangle(rect.X + PrevRecY, (TallestRectangle - rect.Height), rect.Width, rect.Height));
    PrevRecY += rect.Width; // note the +=
  }
}
```

As for the `static Random`, just declare the variable outside the method and use it inside, like that:

```
private static Random ran = new Random();
void GetRandomRectangle()
{
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;

  int width = ran.Next(100, 500);
  int height = ran.Next(200, 700);

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this works! Now that they are stacked vertically I need to calculate the output rectangles and and then display them horizontally, while keeping them in the same shape they were when stacked vertically.

Comment: If you got vertically stacking covered, you should easily get to horizontally stacking on your own. Basically calculate the widest rectangle, calculate the position accordingly and `+=` the height. What is the "output rectangle"? Is that the surrounding rectangle, enclosing all the displayed ones? That should have the same height as tallesRectangle and the width should be the sum of all widths.

Comment: this is basically what I have to achieve: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/139053

Comment: Oh, okay, the rest is "just math". Basically you start at the bottom and go up until you reach the end of the smallest (in height) rectangle. Now you have your first big rectangle with the height of the smallest and the width of all widths combined. And you divided the rest in two parts. Except if the smallest one is at the beginning or end, then you only have one part left. if you have more than one smallest rectangle, you have a maximum of n+1 parts left. maybe less if those smallest ones are next to each other or at the beginning or end. Now for those parts do the same as for the original.

Comment: Try figure that algorithm out on your own. And if you have problems implementing it, ask a new question here on SO. (And be as detailed as possible ^_^)

Comment: I am so confused...lol, please could you maybe elaborate a little bit more and if you would be so kind as to pop in a few basic lines of code so I can just get an idea. I presume that I would have to loop through my current rectanglesCollection to get my shortest rectangle?